# Difference betwen ng build and ionic build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, github-actions

I have a PWA project based on Ionic Angular. 
I want to use GitHub Actions, so that when I push the changes, my projects get built and deployed on Google Firebase Hosting.

In prepared **package.json** with specification of `"build-prod": "ionic build --prod"`.

And in my **main.yml** file I specified the steps:

```
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build-prod
```

**Install Dependencies** step went well. However, GitHub Actions showed an error on **Build** step:

```
Run npm run build-prod

> my-project@0.0.1 build-prod /home/runner/work/my-project/my-project
> ionic build --prod

sh: 1: ionic: not found
```

As I have understood the simple reason is that GitHub Actions did not know what *ionic* was. 
However, when I tried to use

```
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
```

which by default used: `ng build`, GitHub Actions managed to executed the **Build** step successfully.
When I used `ng build --prod` success was also observed.

However, I need to execute `ionic build --prod` command. And therefore, I wanted to know what is the difference between `ionic build` and `ng build`? Will execution of this commands result in the same output, or does `ionic build` do different things than `ng build` do?

I must add, that when I run `ionic build --prod`, my console prints the following message: `ng.cmd run app:build:production`
Could this message give some clue to my problem solution for making an ionic production build with GitHub Actions?

Comment: Does your package.json have dependency on [`@ionic/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/cli)?

Comment: No, it has @angular/cli, but no mention of @ionic/cli

Comment: You will prrobably need that dependency for this to work

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know-

1. `ionic build` uses `ng build` internally.
2. If you run `ng build` directly, [Ionic hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#hooks) won't be triggered as it is bypassed.

Also being discussed here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/difference-betwen-npm-run-build-ng-build-and-ionic-build/187122

Answer (score 2):

To be really sure that you won't miss something you should probably stick with using `ionic` to build since it may also change what it does in the future. The `ionic` command is part of the [@ionic/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/cli) package. You have some options here to make it available:

- Install it globally in your build environment (I don't known if this is possible with GitHub actions)
- Include it as a dependency in your project. You can then run it with:

  - `npx ionic build --prod`; [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) is often included with `npm`
  - add `ionic build --prod` [as a script in your `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts); then you can run `npm run <script name>`

As you mention `build-prod` already being in your `package.json` it seems the latter is already in place. In that case all you need to do is to include `ionic` as a dependency so it is installed *locally* and not required to be available *globally*:

```sh
npm i --save @ionic/cli
```